# Handling locking in incremental load

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have an incremental load routine for our warehouse that uses Rowversion to get most of the latest changes in our OLTP database. It runs every 10 minutes and gets stuck once or twice a day.

Nearly all the tables it pulls from have a `(NOLOCK)` hint apart from the two that containing ROWVERSIONs being tested for. (we're only testing for changes on the two most updated tables. The rest can be dealt with by the full overnight re-population. That presents some of its own risks but we seem to be getting away with it. )

I'm guessing that this hang is happening where we hit a persistent block on a record in that table. Seeing as total consistency isn't vital in our warehouse I'd like to `(READPAST)` on those rowversion tested tables and just pick those locked ones up the next time they're free.

Is there a simple way to do that efficiently? I've got an idea or two but they seem too complicated for me to have understood row versioning properly.

Essentially, I don't mind a record taking 20 min to reach consistency instead of 10 but I do mind missing the committed version of a record altogether by resorting to `(NOLOCK)` on that ROWVERSION sensitive table.

Comment: Where does the block come from? From updating those tables?

Comment: I haven't been able to figure it out fully but I'm thinking so. What are the other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a consistent state of the data in those tables, you should not use `(NOLOCK)`.

As for `(READPAST)`, it may be tricky to use it because depending on the nature of the lock existing on the table when you're reading it, you may get some or no records and you will have to somehow reconcile it with the state of the system you have in your code.

If the tables are blocked by an update, I would try to understand it better and see why the update should take so long. If it's a massive update, maybe you should just increase the timeout on reading the data and/or accept that from time to time you may not be able to read it.

I can't give a solid solution as much depends on the details of your system which I don't have.

Comment: Thanks but I guess I'm asking what is standard operating procedure for someone attempting to implement an __eventually__ consistent sync. The best I can think of is to use READPAST and log all the RowVersions that have been processed. To get all the missed ones when they're done you'd switch `WHERE RowVersion > @LastProcessedRowVersion` 
to
 `WHERE RowVersion NOT IN (Select RowVersion FROM All_RowVersions_Processed_Today)`

I'm not sure how performative that could be made to be and you'd need to have nightly total syncs so as to limit to just looking in present day.

Comment: Yes, sounds reasonable. I think READPAST is not much used though so there's probably no one standard approach.

Comment: In the end I decided that you're right; if any transaction is taking that long then that's the issue but I no longer think it was in this case. With that in mind I've gone with just reading uptil `Min_Active_Rowvrersion()` and setting up an auto email to fire if it lags behind the latest RowVersion `@@DBTS` for too long. We sync every 10 minutes but I don't think most users of the reporting system will get too itchy till it's been over an hour. We'll see how that goes. Am I right in thinking that long running non-serializable Selects present their own consistency issues?

Comment: Yes,I think that long running non-serializable Selects are an issue as they leave shared locks if you don't read as read uncommitted. It depends on the nature of the system but they prevent updates and inserts so may hurt bad in some cases.

Comment: Oh right, that's worse than I thought. I read that they released the lock as soon as the data was read. I was thinking more along the lines that if you got stopped for 30 minutes halfway through, the data you've already picked up might no longer make sense in light of the rest of it once you finally get to it. Also, I get the impression that it fetches in a predetermined order instead of picking up everything it can get and saving the locked records till last.

Comment: The order of fetching the data depends on the execution plan. And yes, locks are held until the end of query or transaction.